# MarkupBuilder Rendering From String

Tags: grails, groovy, markupbuilder

I'm using MarkupBuilder to render some HTML from a taglib like so (stripped down for clarity):

```
def formContainer = new MarkupBuilder(out)
formConainer.form() {
   input() { }
   input() { }
}
```

Now assume that somewhere inside the form() I want to pull in some elements specified by a user so in a file on the file system I have something like this (again, simplified)...

```
select() {
  option()
  option()
}
```

My question is, if I read that select in as a String, is there a way for the taglib to parse it as groovy and make it part of the MarkupBuilder instance?

```
def formContainer = new MarkupBuilder(out)
formConainer.form() {
   input() { }
   input() { }

   // I want the select to render here
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for doing this would be:

```
String externalMarkup = '''
select() {
  option()
  option()
}
'''
def out = new StringWriter()

def formContainer = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( out )
formContainer.form() {
   input()
   input()

   // Wrap the string in { -> ... } to make it a closure, and evaluate it
   def extern = new GroovyShell().evaluate( "{ it-> ${externalMarkup} }" )
   // Set the delegate of this closure to the MarkupWriter
   extern.delegate = formContainer
   // Then execute the closure
   extern()
}
println out.toString()
```

However, this feels brittle to me...

A better method might be to use the [GroovyTemplateEngine](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Templates) to inject your values into a formatted complete bit of markup

Comment: I like the GroovyTemplateEngine approach (I've used this before).  Do you know if there is a way to get access to the Grails taglibs in the template?

Comment: Hmmmm....no, come to think of it I don't :-(  I wonder if you could just use a GSP for this?

Comment: Well, without going into too much detail this has to be something an end user can put into our system and it get rendered correctly.  Kind of like a CMS but not nearly as fancy.

Comment: Might be worth a look inside the [weceem app](https://github.com/jCatalog/weceem-app) I'm pretty sure that lets you declare tags inside the content (I may be wrong though)...  Marc Palmer is your man (as is often the case) ;-)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check on that.  In the meantime I'm getting by with {% %}.  yuck, but gets me moving.